# Wilks's lambda distribution

Tags: distributions, density-function, wishart-distribution

Please help me, I don´t have any idea how to solve this problem. If $\textbf{A} \sim W_p(\mathbf{\Sigma}, m)$ and $\textbf{B} \sim W_p(\mathbf{\Sigma}, m)$ are independent Wishart matrices, show that $|\textbf{A}|/|\textbf{A}+\textbf{B}|$ has the $\Lambda(p,m,n)$ Wilk's lambda distribution.

I would be very grateful if someone could guide me.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27s_lambda_distribution , this is true by definition of the Lambda distribution, citing Mardia, Kent and Bibby.